# Changing _init_ defined attribute in another class method Python

Tags: python, pycharm

I am new to Python , so this might be a stupid question.
I wrote this :

```
Class A:
    def _init_(self):
        self.var1 = 2

    def update(self):
        self.var1 = 3
```

But constantly getting the error in PyCharm : instance attribute var1 is defined outside *init*. Why?

Comment: Because it is: `'_init_' != '__init__'`. @S.R. it will run, but it probably won't work as the OP expects.

Comment: @jonrsharpe - Nice catch! If they use inheritance it will be a problem

Answer (score 1):

The reason you are getting the error is due to typo error.
Please replace '_' with double underscore while writing init() and similar functions. Correct code is as follows :

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.var1 = 3
    def update(self):
        self.var1 = 4
```

Comment: 1. Indentation matters in Python. 2. Typo questions should be closed as such, there's no point answering them.

Comment: I am new to the answering platform and would like to help where I used to go wrong. Cheers !